When is the set of proper sub-varieties countable
I am reading a paper that claims if $X$ is a variety defined over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, then the set of proper sub-varieties is countable. I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is true. I know $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is countable and algebraically closed, so I assume this is why, but I do not actually understand why it's true. Thank you for the help!

The basic idea is that any subvariety is defined by finitely many polynomials (this number can be bounded by fixing an embedding of $X$ into projective space), each of which has finitely many coefficients, and each coefficient is chosen from the countable field $\bar {\mathbb Q}$. This is quite sketchy, but you should get the idea.

@TabesBridges Thank you for the reply! That's what I was thinking in the projective case, and I know abelian varieties are projective schemes, but is it true they are all defined by polynomial equations in such a way?

Yes, any projective scheme is defined by polynomials.

@TabesBridges perfect! Thank you for your help!
